# retrieving session via cross domain ajax

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, session, cookies

## Background:

I'm developing a website tracker using javascript. Here's how it works:

1) A user visits any domain the tracker script is on "anydomain.com". The script makes a successful ajax call in the background to my master domain "masterdomain.com".

2) When "masterdomain.com" receives a request, the following PSEUDO code is run. It works by checking for an existing session and if one doesnt exist it creates a new one.

The first call appears to be fine because I am able to receive a session ID in a response. However, each successive call to "masterdomain.com" creates a new session. AKA the server doesn't find the "should be" existing session.

## Sample PSEUDO Code:

```
if(session exists)
{
// update timestamp for session
}
else
{
// set a new session for visitor
}

// load template
api(array("accepted"=>session_id),callback);
```

## Some Quick Facts:

1) This does not appear to be a same origin issue (as I am able to communicate with the server fine).

2) I have tried this with cookies/sessions both appear to not be working.

3) I am using codeigniter (sessions are set not to expire on page close). I have also tried using/not using database sessions).

This problem can also be solved if there is another way to uniquely identify a user each time a page loads on a server (not using IP).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm about ready to tear the rest of my hair out of my head!!!! :(

Comment: sessions are domain specific

Comment: Sounds like third party cookie issue to me. Browsers surfing any page would not simply accept cookies from your domain.

Comment: @Dragon, I know sessions are domain specific, but in my example the session is only being called/set on the master domain. I dont ever try to access it on the external domain. Is there another reason?

Comment: You must define a cookie to be used from other domains which you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is incomplete in that you'll have to do some additional research, but the easiest way (which is not actually particularly 'easy') to do this is to use Javascript to place a hidden iframe to masterdomain.com, and set up iframe communication (e.g. using postMessage) to retrieve the session from that iframe to your page.

Answer (score 0):

With AJAX calls you can only send/set session cookies if the URL you're calling is on the same domain as your calling script. I think you should create an iframe, call ajax from within and it should work fine. By the way, I have no idea what you are trying to track.